# Beautiful Soup UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract only text from a source code (html codes which is div id "col-green"). There is a warning when I want to extract only text in the source_code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_link = 'http://drneclayazicioglu.meb.k12.tr/'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
source_code=(page_content.findAll('div',attrs={"id":"col-green"}))
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)   #error line here...
```

**Error is that:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/Emre/Desktop/python.py", line 7
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 7 of the file C:/Users/Emre/Desktop/python.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

Comment: In line 7 write `soup = source_code.getText()` to extract text.

Comment: unfortunately not working...

Comment: What's the new error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use again `BeautifulSoup`. Your `source_code` returns `bs4.element.ResultSet` and you can get text with like this :

```
for a in source_code:
    print a.text
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Duyurular
Ocak 2019 GELİR LİSTEMİZ 11.02.2019 00:18GİDER LİSTEMİZ OCAK AYI11.02.2019 
00:11Yönetici Görevlendirme Yönetmeliğinde Değişiklik10.02.2019 23:512018-2019 
ÖGRETIM YILI  ÖĞRETMENLER KURULU TOPLANTISI YAPILDI05.02.2019 18:49BİN DÖRT YÜZ 
ÖĞRENCİ 5 YETİME KARDEŞ OLDU!!!06.01.2019 11:18 
Devamı...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_link = 'http://drneclayazicioglu.meb.k12.tr/'
page_content= BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_link).text, "html.parser")
source_code=(page_content.findAll('div',attrs={"id":"col-green"}))
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
```

I hope this works!